# What should we do with off-topic bounty questions?

Tags: support, bounty, vote-to-close

This [Bounty question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81591/11083) looks to me as if it were

- off topic and
- a crosspost

For this question - assume it were off-topic.

How should these kind of questions be handled?

Close and Flag for moving do not work on bounty-questions.

IMO this should be deleted/closed by a moderator.

The detail question is - should the bounty be reawarded to the OP in this progress yes or no?

Comment: Something like this was asked on main Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14591.

Comment: @Tshepang I see a bias towards refunding there.

Comment: I'm not actually convinced it's offtopic... the problem seems to be a terminal one, I could be wrong, but that seems like what is being discussed.

Comment: If it is off-topic here, where else should it be asked?

Comment: @manatwork this looks like a PHP problem. PHP is a programming language that does not belong to the core-installation. SuperUser ist there for programming questions. But I will edit my question.

Comment: @xenoterracide I reworded my question to get to the core of the question. That is not related to a specific question.

Answer (score 4):

It should be flagged for moderator attention, this question already was. The crosspost was removed of StackOverflow, and although this question originally really read like it was a PHP problem, a very close read instead made it seem more like a terminal problem or expectation problem. The accepted answer also confirms this.